# Bind column to a different entity source than the gridview is

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I have a gridview bound to an Entity DataSource (Permissions).  One of the columns lists a UserId, which is the primary key in another table.  How do I go about replacing that UserId with the corresponding Name form the Users Entity DataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ApprovedBy" SortExpression="ApprovedBy" >
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"  Text='<%# GetApprover(Eval("ApprovedBy").ToString()) %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and code behind:

```
protected string GetApprover(string ApproverId)
    {
        int approver = Convert.ToInt32(ApproverId);
        var approversList = (from a in EntUsers.Users
                             where a.UserId == approver
                            select a.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        return approversList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" >
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentEntityName.Name")%>'
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That worked.. Thanks.   Now what if the gridview was bound to the Users table, and a row contained the userid of another user.. 
i.e. User 533 has a parent user 221.  How would I get it to display the name of user 221 in that row?

Comment: You are talking parent child in the same table ?

Comment: Same table.. I.e  Id = 123 Name = Bob Parent = 224 |  id = 224 Name = Steve Parent = 5324.  I want to replace Parent with the Name.  So in the case of Id = 123, it would have Parent = Steve

Comment: If it have parent Child relation then It will be in the same way what I have mention in answer.

Comment: There is no parent child relationship.. Parent was probably the wrong word to use.. Call it approver instead.. It simply holds the userid of the person that approved that users access.  I need it like this for another section of the site.. howerver here, I want it to convert to the name

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lookup in your Users Entity Source the RowDataBound event of the Gridview.

Comment: Do you have a link to somewhere that describes this better?